# Marketing Cloud API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api, integration, einstein-recommendations

I am new for Marketing Cloud API code and trying to fetch records from **IGO_PROFILES** data extension through marketing cloud API..

I want to know where to write these APIs and how to write it?

Answer (score 2):

You are best downloading this via the UI. If you do choose to go the API route, try the instructions here: [Retrieving Data Extension with CustomKey](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_dataextension_object.htm) or [Retrieving Data From Data Extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_data_from_a_data_extension.htm)

For more information on how to interact with SFMC Webservices, visit [HERE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/index-api.htm).

A few pointers:

1. You would need to create an API Key and retreive your Client Id and Client Secret
2. You have the choice of either using the SDKs (built on soap) or raw REST/SOAP calls.

Hope this helps

Comment: I have created  Client Id and Client Secret.So is there is any place in marketing cloud to write API or some where else..

Comment: You can either use a package like PostMan or SOAP UI or make the call using any langauge of your choice that supports REST/ POST Calls

Comment: A good place to start : https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/postman/blob/master/SFMC.json.postman_collection

Comment: Depending on your use case, you can use them within marketing cloud eg. Starting an automation after sending an email